# AWS Linux EC2 - How to install suPHP or FastCGI php hander

Tags: amazon-ec2, fastcgi, chown, suphp, mod-fastcgi

Seems I'm having permissions issue with AWS Linux EC2.  Specifically, I am migrating a Joomla site, and extension and core updates from Joomla Admin won't install because of Apache user/group permission issues.

I've done some digging and seems an unsuitable PHP file handler is to blame and I need to be install either suPHP or FastCGI.

Other really BAD workarounds are messing with directory permissions (777) or chown apache:apache.

I can't find a resource ANYWHERE that will give me a good understanding of how to install/configure suPHP or FastCGI with an AWS Linux instance.  Even AWS has no documentation on this, and usually their docs are superb.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: What distro are you using? If Amazon Linux, give up getting it to work and start over with CentOS. When you do that, don't expect to find AWS documentation that will help you. AWS provides your **infrastructure**. It's up to you to do everything below that. Any CentOS documentation you find will be applicable to your server running on EC2.

Comment: Why would you say chwon apache:apache is a bad workaround? What are your expected permission settings?